# Can PyQt QWebPage linkClicked signal detect which mouse button was used

Tags: python, qt, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm currently connecting this signal with a function that handles the click.  For example:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.webView, QtCore.SIGNAL("linkClicked (const QUrl&)"), self.navigate)

def navigate(self, url):
    #do something
```

What I'd like to is for the for the navigate function to know if the link was clicked on by the left or right mouse button.  Something like

```
def navigate(self, url, event):
    if event == Qt.LeftClick:
        #do something
    if event == Qt.MidClick:
        #do something else
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another method is reimplementing the `mousePressEvent` and filtering mouse events there:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class myWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.label.setText("Click Me")

        self.layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)


    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.label.setText("Left Mouse Click!")

        elif event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            self.label.setText("Right Mouse Click!")

        return super(myWindow, self).mousePressEvent(event)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('myWindow')

    main = myWindow()
    main.resize(150, 150)
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

You should subclass `QWebView`, and override [`mousePressEvent`](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qwebview.html#mousePressEvent). You could store in a variable the button that was pressed using the [`button()`](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qmouseevent.html#button) function of the `QMouseEvent` .

In your slot you can simply check the value of the last button pressed and handle it the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the docs there's some information on which buttons have been pressed in the QMouseEvent and you can handle them inside an event filter: [QMouseEvent.button docs](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qmouseevent.html#button).